# Why Azure Load Balancer gets created in AKS even though I have used AppGateway as an Ingress Controller?

Tags: azure, azure-aks

I've created a Kubernetes cluster in Azure using the following Terraform. As you see clearly, I have passed the AppGateway ID to ingress_application_gateway.

```
# Create the Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) Cluster
resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "kubernetes_cluster" {
  count                         = var.enable_kubernetes == true ? 1 : 0
  name                          = "aks-prjx-${var.subscription_type}-${var.environment}-${var.location}-${var.instance_number}"    
  location                      = var.location
  resource_group_name           = module.resource_group_kubernetes_cluster[0].name  # "rg-aks-spoke-dev-westus3-001"
  dns_prefix                    = "dns-aks-prjx-${var.subscription_type}-${var.environment}-${var.location}-${var.instance_number}" #"dns-prjxcluster"
  private_cluster_enabled       = false
  local_account_disabled        = true

  default_node_pool {
    name                        = "npprjx${var.subscription_type}" #"prjxsyspool" # NOTE: "name must start with a lowercase letter, have max length of 12, and only have characters a-z0-9."
    vm_size                     = "Standard_B8ms"
    vnet_subnet_id              = data.azurerm_subnet.aks-subnet.id
    # zones                     = ["1", "2", "3"]
    enable_auto_scaling         = true
    max_count                   = 3
    min_count                   = 1
    # node_count                = 3
    os_disk_size_gb             = 50
    type                        = "VirtualMachineScaleSets"
    enable_node_public_ip       = false
    enable_host_encryption      = false

    node_labels = {
      "node_pool_type"          = "npprjx${var.subscription_type}"
      "node_pool_os"            = "linux"
      "environment"             = "${var.environment}"
      "app"                     = "prjx_${var.subscription_type}_app"
    }
    tags = var.tags
  }

  ingress_application_gateway {
    gateway_id = azurerm_application_gateway.network.id
  }

  # Enabled the cluster configuration to the Azure kubernets with RBAC
  azure_active_directory_role_based_access_control { 
    managed                     = true
    admin_group_object_ids      = var.active_directory_role_based_access_control_admin_group_object_ids
    azure_rbac_enabled          = true #false
  }

  network_profile {
    network_plugin              = "azure"
    network_policy              = "azure"
    outbound_type               = "userDefinedRouting"
  }

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }  

  oms_agent {
    log_analytics_workspace_id  = module.log_analytics_workspace[0].id
  }

  timeouts {
    create = "20m"
    delete = "20m"
  }

  depends_on = [
    azurerm_application_gateway.network
  ]
}
```

I was thinking that AppGateway will be used as the Ingress Gateway. However, AKS creates the Azure Load Balancer while trying to deploy the Service like mentioned below

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: aks-helloworld 
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 80
  selector:
    app: aks-helloworld-two
```

Is there a reason for this Load Balancer and AppGateway not being used? I would assume that Load balancer is used for type **LoadBalancer** and App Gateway is used for **Ingress**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I tried to reproduce the same in my environment to create a Service with Application Gateway Ingress Controller:**

Since you mentioned service **type: Load balancer** in your **yaml** file, it is creating load balancing service,
Inorder to create service with **Application Gateway Ingress Controller** without an associated Load Balancer, kindly follow the below steps.

1.First, you need to create a deployment for your application with the desired replicas and the desired image.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: test-app
spec:
 replicas: 2
 selector:
  matchLabels:
  app: nginx
template:
 metadata:
   name: test-app
   labels:
     app: nginx
   spec:
     containers:
     - name: nginx
     image: "nginx:latest"
     ports:
     - containerPort: 80
```

cmd to check the deployed app `kubectl get deploy`

[image]

2 Next, you can create a service for your application with **type:ClusterIP**.

> Note: if you create a service **type:LoadBalancer** for your application. This service will create with Load Balancer.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
    name: nginx-service
     labels:
       app: nginx
   spec:
     selector:
       app: nginx
     ports:
       - port: 80
          targetPort: 80
          protocol: TCP
```

Service created with **type: ClusterIP.**

cmd to check the service: `kubectl get svc`

[image]

3. Create an ingress resource for your application to route the traffic to the service

.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
    kind: Ingress
    metadata:
      name: nginxapp
    annotations:
       kubernetes.io/ingress.class: azure/application-gateway
     spec:
        rules:
        - http:
         paths:
        - pathType: Exact
          path: /
          backend:
           service:
             name: nginx-service
           port:
             number: 80
```

Ingress created successfully.

[image]

4. Once all resources are created Application **Gateway Ingress Controller** will route the traffic to the service without creating an associated load balancer.

Application is running successfully with application gateway public IP.

[image]